# Can i automate a shellscript that will run a python file which asks for user input?

Tags: shell, terminal

I know how to run shell scripts pretty easily.

I would have my file say:

```
#!/bin/zsh
python somefile.py
```

but the file, somefile in this case requires an input.  example:

```
What is the password?
```

Can you write a script which will enter that password, or have pause while it waits for input?

My goal overall, is to run a tunneling python script to build a connection and watch a port, pull some data through the tunnel, and then close the python script.

Ideally:  I want to have this shellscript option somefile.py in an alternate terminal, as i dont know if i can just no-hup until it is no longer needed then kill the process.

First thing is first.  Can you have script which will do something like:

```
#!/bin/zsh
python somefile.py
echo admin12345
```

or something similar to auto enter info?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the python script reads from stdin, just do "echo admin12345 | somefile.py".

Usually, however, that's not the case, and scripts that read passwords will want to read from a terminal, not just any stdin.

In that case, look into "expect".

Comment: Just took a peek.  It seems like that might be usable.  Can you possibly give an example, using the example given in the question??  Im looking at the man-page for it, and like some man pages confuses me slightly.

Comment: Ill give this as the answer if i can build a functional sample

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me with `java` and `python` examples:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1234" | python somefile.py
```

Just give some permissions to your script `chmod +x yourscript.sh`, and run it `./yourscript.sh`.

Comment: So that works with the idea of:
script runs for a bit.  Pauses to let user insert data, then the echo puts 1234 in there, and the script continues?   For some reason doing it that way, i thought would just make it be a param of the script and not passed in at the first point of user input.  Figured it would be harder then for when you need to have 2 or 3 script pauses for user input and then manage what goes in where.

Comment: this does not work in the question i am asking.  That puts it as a parameter, I was talking about when a script pauses, awaiting input from the user/console to be typed.